# Google spreadsheet: Value parameter can not be parsed

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, custom-function

I'm using this [script](https://github.com/fastfedora/google-docs/blob/master/scripts/ImportJSON/Code.gs) to integrate ImportJSON inside my google sheet.
The command I'm performing is:

```
=IF(B4="";"";VALUE(ImportJSON("https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym="&B4&"&tsyms=USD";"/USD";"noHeaders";$L$1))*$C$2)
```

Where B4 contains: "BTC" and [this](https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=BTC&tsyms=USD) is the value I got returned.

Now I see my value in an errorbox:

> Value parameters 1423.42 can not be parsed to a number.

The number contains a dot ('.'). I don't know if that's the problem?

Someone knows how to fix this in my case?

Answer (score 1):

This formula gives no error for me:

```
=IF(B4="","",VALUE(ImportJSON("https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=BTC&tsyms=USD","/USD","noHeaders","/feed/entry/title,/feed/entry/content")))
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
=IF(B4="";"";VALUE(substitute(ImportJSON("https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym="&B4&"&tsyms=EUR";"/EUR";"noHeaders";$L$1);".";","))*$C$2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try splitting the number which is being detected as text with "," and "." and then individually using VALUE function before combining it into desired output.